# bitwise XOR checksum for a single value?

Tags: python

I'm doing a bitwise checksum for arrays.

```
0^1^2^3^4^6 == 2.

17^18^19^20^21^22^23^25^26^29 == 14.

12^ == ?
```

However sometimes there might be a single value.

What would be the equivalent of array checksum for a single value?

Comment: can you post the code you have tried

Comment: Usually you start the checksum calculation with a "reference" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: `X^0 == X` for any `X`, that's why result for 12 equals `12^0`, i.e. 12.

---

I'm not mathematically precise, but for an operation there may exist a "neutral" value doing nothing:

- for addition it is 0: `X+0 == X`
- for multiplication it is 1: `X*1 == X`
- for AND (logical, bitwise) it is `True` or bit value 1

etc.

You can always insert the neutral value without changing the result. This implies that e.g. the sum of an empty list of numbers is 0 and the product is 1. You would naturally use that value as a starting point in a `sum(alist)` or `product(alist)` implementation:

```
total = 0; for x in alist: total = total + x

prod = 1; for x in alist: prod = prod * x
```

Back to your question, the neutral value for XOR is 0. We would write xor as:

```
def xor(*args):
    result = 0
    for x in args:
        result ^= x
    return result
```

and then:

```
>>> xor(17,18,19,20,21,22,23,25,26,29)
14
>>> xor(0,1,2,3,4,6)
2
>>> xor()
0
>>> xor(12)
12
```